# javascript - get selected value from select list

Tags: javascript

i got a form with a select form elements for month.

```
<select id="month" name="month">
<option value="Jan">Jan</option>
<option value="Feb">Feb</option>
<option>Mar
<option>Apr
<option>May
<option>Jun
<option>Jul
<option>Aug
<option>Sept
<option>Oct
<option>Nov
<option>Dec
</select>
```

How do i use javascript to get compare the selected value. for example if i select Feb, the javascript will pop up "you selected feb"

```
var monthSelect = document.getElementById("month")
var opt = monthSelect.options[monthSelect.selectedIndex]
if(opt.text == "Feb")
{
    alert("Feb selected")
    return false
}
```

Comment: You haven't closed most of your options `</option>` And why not just use `document.getElementById("month").value` ...? Also you need to attach an event listener or an attribute event handler

Comment: @NewToJS `<option>` is a tag with optional closing tag. It's better if you close, but it's not invalid. Exactly like `<li>` or `<td>`

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude agreed but it is very bad practice.

Comment: I agree with the `element.value` suggestion. As simple as `alert(document.getElementById("month").value+ " selected");`

Comment: @BenYep you're also missing a couple of semi colons at  the end of your javascript

Comment: @NewToJS hi, i have close all my options and use `document.getElementById("month").value` but its still not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ebrnh047/

Your html:

```
<select id="month">
  <option value="Jan">Jan</option>
  <option value="Feb">Feb</option>
</select>
```

Try:

```
var month = document.getElementById("month");

month.onchange = function() {
  if (month.value == "Feb") {
    alert("Feb selected");
  }
}
```

Comment: @BenYap just updated, try it now. You have to but an event handler.

Comment: For this to work you will need to place the script tag after the html element otherwise it will cause an error.

Comment: is still not working.. how can i paste my whole code to show

Comment: @BenYap added jsfiddle link, take a look

Comment: @dev-l gotten my jsfiddle?

Comment: @dev-l actually i want to check if month == feb and if day is more then 29. then it prompt and alert. invalid date.. this happen when the submit button is press and it will run the Validate()

Comment: @BenYap https://jsfiddle.net/e0vxmxzt/1/ fixed your issue. When you press send, and if the month Feb, it will alert a message.

Comment: @dev-l btw why if i put the code after my checkemail.. it doesnt work.. however it only works when the code is placed right after "var"

Comment: @BenYap its because you have multiple conditions that `return` from the function. You have to fill everything correctly first, so it passed validation.

Answer (score 0):

This is a way to do it with JavaScript only:

First, your HTML:

```
<select id="month" name="month">
  <option value="Jan">Jan</option>
  <option value="Feb">Feb</option>
  <option value="Mar">Mar</option>
  <option value="Apr">Apr</option>
  <option value="May">May</option>
  <option value="Jun">Jun</option>
  <option value="Jul">Jul</option>
  <option value="Aug">Aug</option>
  <option value="Sep">Sep</option>
  <option value="Oct">Oct</option>
  <option value="Nov">Nov</option>
  <option value="Dec">Dec</option>
</select>
```

Then, your script:

```
var monthSelect = document.getElementById("month");

monthSelect.onchange = function(){
  var thisValue = this.value;
  alert(thisValue); 
};
```

This is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/16sn90tp/

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you execute this code on document ready event( window.onload )

```js
  var monthSelect = document.getElementById("month")
  monthSelect.onchange = function() {

    var opt = monthSelect.options[monthSelect.selectedIndex]
    if (opt.text == "Feb") {
      alert("Feb selected")
    }
  }
```

```html
   <select id="month" name="month">
<option value="Jan">Jan</option>
<option value="Feb">Feb</option>
<option>Mar
<option>Apr
<option>May
<option>Jun
<option>Jul
<option>Aug
<option>Sept
<option>Oct
<option>Nov
<option>Dec
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Jan Feb
```

```js
    function myFunction() {
        var monthSelect = document.getElementById("month").value;
        if (monthSelect == "Feb") {
            alert("Feb selected");
            return false;
        }
    }
```

```html
<select id="month" name="month" onchange="myFunction()">
  <option value="Jan">Jan</option> 
  <option value="Feb">Feb</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score -1):

Hi add at first a class called "month" to all of your option tags and one class "monthList" to the select like for example this:

```
<select class="monthList">
    <option class="month">Jan</option>
    <option class="month">Feb</option>
    <option class="month">Mar</option>
    ...
</select>
```

After this you need a little bit of JQuery:

```
$(".monthList .month").click(function(){
    var selectedMonth = $(this).text();
    var showText = "you selected " + selectedMonth;
    alert(showText);
});
```

Try this, it should work.

Comment: This is not tagged as [tag:jquery]. So your answer is not correct

Comment: I don't downvote, for your information, I only write the comment.

Comment: Agreed, jQuery isn't tagged in this question so if you wish to offer a jQuery solution is would be best that you clearly display how to include the jQuery library.

Comment: Yes, i forgott to look, my fault :)